# Safari video element doesn't trigger error event on 403 response

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video, dom-events, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to load a video from S3 that may or may not be transcoding at the time. While it's still processing, I get a 403 response. Every other browser I test (Chrome/Firefox/IE) triggers the "error" event so I can display a message to the user like so:

```js
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.onerror = function (e) {
// Show the user a message...
};
video.src = videoURL;
```

But Safari (on OSX) just logs to the console without triggering the event.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

It will trigger if I make the video.src a garbage URL that leads to nothing but it doesn't for a 403.

Is there some other event I can listen for or another way to warn the user? I know I could probably make a separate ajax request for the video and check the response but I'd like to avoid the overhead.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @pruebaprueba No, I never did, but I haven't checked Safari again in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Webkit.

We handle this by first making a HEAD request to check the status of the file, before trying to load the video. Adds a round-trip, but is usually pretty fast:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "HEAD",
  url: video_filename,
  success: loadVideo,
  error: handleError
});
```